# ddd hangs on start

Tags: gdb, ddd-debugger

When I start ddd, it seems hang waiting for gdb. Here is the tail end of output `ddd --trace`:

```
#  Saving session in "/home/kbrandt/.ddd/sessions/106d7eb3d567f23b01125736049734486400000041300582/init"...
#  Saving session in "/home/kbrandt/.ddd/sessions/106d7eb3d567f23b01125736049734486400000041300582/init"...done.
2009.11.04 13:48:17
<- "(gdb)  "
```

This doesn't happen if I pick a different debugger like `--perl`.  I read about adding `set prompt (gdb)` to `~/.gdbinit` (space at end), but that doesn't fix it.  gdb starts fine on its own.  Anyone know what this might be?

Comment: Also tried removing ~/.ddd recursively

Comment: Seems to be limited it to my account on the machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the following in my inputrc, removing it fixed it:

> \C-j": "|less\C-m

...shrug.

Answer (score 20):

remove ~/.ddd by using command

> sudo rm -rf ~/.ddd

Answer (score 3):

I've run into this issue and other similar ones with ddd hanging on startup. Each has been fixed by removing ~/.ddd/init

```
rm ~/.ddd/init
```